# Importing file content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

I am converting `md` files to `html` in my `React` project but having trouble importing the contents of an md file which is getting passed to a `React` component. How do I get the contents of a local file in `js`?

Suppose I have this text

```
const md = `
   # A title
   Some text
`;
```

I then pass this into a `react-markdown` component:

```
<ReactMarkdown source={md} />
```

But this can get messy if I have a lot of long `markdown` constants. So instead, I would like to import various files that have `markdown` content in it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your development setup? like is it a `CRA` or some custom setup? and also please share some code snippet.

Comment: Added some code for clarification

Comment: This link has a similar question https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown/issues/76

Comment: Awesome, I will update this question with an answer